# Boolean Ring and prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-algebra

Referring to the question:
[Finitely generated ideals in a Boolean ring are principal, why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110329/168520)

How to prove: In every Boolean Ring
Does there exist any prime ideal in a Boolean Ring. Only Boolean ring I know is power set any set with symmetric difference and intersection. But there is no prime ideal as much as I can figure out. 
Only case is $\mathbb Z_{2}$ also there are no prime ideals except $\{0\}$

Comment: So   are  you  studying   _commutative_  _algebra_  $?$   See  the  link  .  Might   help .   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877892/finitely-generated-ideal-in-boolean-ring-how-do-we-motivate-the-generator

Comment: I am planning to. But how this links helps. I didn't get any idea about prime ideals in Boolean Ring only fact these are maximal. But are there any prime ideal in a boolean ring. @user118494

Comment: How did you conclude that the power set ring has no prime ideals?

Comment: If P prime ideal in power set ring of X. Let P contains non empty set. Then let A is in P. Now A.X is in P. Hence X is in P. Hence every subset of X is in P. Then P={X} contradiction. Case where P only contains empty set also gives contradiction you can figure that out. I think. @user26857

Comment: @user26857 Oh no how totally spoiled things. But what are prime ideals in any power set ring. Can you please help

Comment: @Sushil You require boolean rings to have identity,right?

Comment: @rschwieb for time being yes. Because I first want to figure out in power set rings, how ideals and prime ideals look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every ring with identity [has a maximal ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/980714/29335) and [every maximal ideal is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255106/29335). You can find several more proofs of these statements on the site, as well as online, or in any algebra book.

For concrete examples, just take $\prod \Bbb Z_2$, any number of copies of the field of two elements. You can produce a maximal ideal (many, actually) by picking a particular position and looking at the set of elements which are zero on that position.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your question is "why is any prime ideal in a boolean ring maximal?". Here's a proof :

Let $R$ be boolean, ie $\forall x \in R, \, x^2 = x$. Then any quotient of $R$ is also boolean.
Let $I$ be a prime ideal of $R$, then $R / I$ is an integral domain. We show that $R/I$ is a field, whence $I$ is maximal.

In fact, every boolean ring $R$ that is an integral domain is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ :

let $x \in R$. Then $x (1 - x) = x - x^2 = x - x = 0$. Since $R$ is an integral domain, that means that either $x=0$ or $1 - x=0$. Hence, $R = \{0;1\}$ as a set. The function $f : R \mapsto \mathbb{F}_2$ defined by $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)=1$ is obviously a ring isomorphism.